# html hex email encoding in pelican does not work

Tags: html, email, pelican

I am building a website in Pelican (beginner) and I am trying to encode my email address. My email address is used on the contact page where you click on an image to initiate the opening of an email (which already has some content).

My contact.rst file includes:

.. raw:: html

```
<a href="mailto:&#112;&#101;&#116;&#115;y&#64;p&#101;&#116;&#115;&#121;&#45;fink.&#99;&#111;&#109;?subject=Inquiry%20about%20a%20photo%20shooting&body=Name%3A%20%0AEmail%3A%20%0ACell%20phone%20number%3A%20%0AType%20of%20shooting%3A%20%0AEvent%20date%3A%0AEvent%20Time%20(from%2Funtil)%3A%20%0APhotographer%20required%20(from%2Funtil)%3A%20%0ALocation%20and%20Country%3A%20%0AReferral%20from%3A%20%0AMessage%3A%0A"><img src="theme/images/nav/contact_image_en_900W.jpg"></a>
```

It works fine BUT it does not keep the encoding. In the page source it shows my real email address. What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While pelican creates html files, it rewrites *everything*, even html sources. That's why your email is rewritten without hex encoding.

You might try out the following simple plugin. Just put `__init.py__` and `hide_links.py` in a folder `hide_links` inside your plugin directory and in your `pelicanconf.py` add `hide_links` as last entry in the `PLUGINS` value. It's important to put this plugin last to avoid the html file being rewritten by pelican after the mail address is obfuscated. Now just write your mail address into `contact.rst` without hex encoding.

`hide_links.py`:

```
"""
Hide Links
----------

adds the possibility to obfuscate email addresses with a random mixture of 
ordinal and hexadecimal chars
"""

from pelican import signals
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random
import re

def obfuscate_string(value):
    ''' Obfuscate mail addresses

    see http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1528/obfuscation-of-text-and-email-addresses
    '''

    result = ''
    for char in value:
        r = random.random()
        # Roughly 20% raw, 40% hex, 40% dec.
        # '@' and '_' are always encoded. 
        if r > 0.8 and char not in "@_":
           result += char
        elif r < 0.4:
            result += '&#%s;' % hex(ord(char))[1:]
        else:
            result += '&#%s;' % str(ord(char))
    return result

def hide_links(htmlDoc, context='localcontext'):

    with open(htmlDoc,'r') as filehandle:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(filehandle.read()) 

    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('mailto')):

        link['href'] = obfuscate_string(link['href'])
        link.contents[0].replaceWith(obfuscate_string(link.contents[0]))

        title = link.get('title')
        if title:
            link['title'] = obfuscate_string(title)

    html = soup.decode(formatter=None)
    html = html.encode('utf-8')
    with open(htmlDoc, "wb") as file:
        file.write(html)

def register():

    signals.content_written.connect(hide_links)
```

`__init.py__`:

```
from .hide_links import *
```

Answer (score 0):

This way of encoding will not hide your email address, because when the browser reads the email it will decode it.

No matter how you encode your email, there will be a way for someone to decode it and read it. If they wanted to find it they could.

If you just want to hide it from bots you could use the javascript `.replace()` function to switch some of the letters around. However if the user has javascript disabled they will not be able to use the form.

Comment: javascript .replace is not an option  - any other idea to hide it from bots?

Comment: Do you not have a business email address that can be used without needing to hide it? Another way to hide the email is to ping a php server for the details and block the bots access to that file with the robots.txt file.

Comment: Thank you, I will follow that thought.

Comment: @Schmiechen No problem, press the tick if my answer solved your official question. (What am I missing?)